# Hyperlink click in WebView within fragment should open in new WebView in activity (tricky)

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview, android-webview

I am using fragment with WebView. Webview opens up correctly. My intention is as follows: Visitor clicks on any of the links within WebView inside the Fragment. Clicked link opens up in new WebView within new Activity. **Tricky part - all links are from the same web site, there are no external links.** Tricky for me, at least. Many thanks for your help in advance! :)

Here is my WebView code from Fragment:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_naslovna, container, false);

    WebView webView = view.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.loadUrl("https://mywebpage.com/");

    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    return view;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
WebViewClient webClient = new WebViewClient(){
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView  view, String  url){
        if( url.equals("http://test.com") ){
            // do whatever you want e.g. open up activity with web view and pass the url
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: We can discuss it here, I forgot to mention add webView.setWebViewClient(webClient); so it will set once your page loads.

Answer (score 0):

It took 6 more hours u puzzle work, but this is how it got fixed at the end.

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

WebView webView;
SwipeRefreshLayout swipeToRefreshLayout;

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_naslovna, container, false);
    webView = view.findViewById(R.id.webView1);

    final String pageUrl = "https://mywebpage.com/";

    swipeToRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.swiperefresh);
    swipeToRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new RtvTkSwipeToRefreshListener(webView, swipeToRefreshLayout));

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (url != pageUrl) {
                startNewActivity(url);
            }
            return true;

        }
    });

    webView.loadUrl(pageUrl);
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    return view;
}

private void startNewActivity(String url) {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), NewActivity.class);
    myIntent.putExtra("url", url);
    getActivity().startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

}